# A. Zee Contour Integral

Tags: homework-and-exercises, integration, mathematics, complex-numbers, calculus

In A.Zee's book I have come a cross an integral which I found difficult to solve.[image]

Comment: What's the difficulty, exactly?

Comment: I never took courses on how to deal with contour integrals

Comment: If you do not understand the explanation Zee gives, it is unlikely that we can help you here. This is very basic contour manipulation, the only way to explain it better that it already is is to teach you complex analysis. The advice is to learn basic complex analysis _before_ studying QFT or string theory or what not.

Comment: As with another recent question: I would suggest you read the following book, and read how the evaluation of these integrals is covered: Mathematical Methods in the Physical Sciences, 3e, (Mary Boas), its a free PDF download

Comment: @Sophie Then you should first learn contour integration. It is used a lot in physics, particularly in QFT. It will take a few days at most to go through the requisite math you need to learn. Arfken's book on mathematical methods has a nice chapter on complex analysis.